# Autopairs shortcut not working

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-auto-pairs

Vim 8 user here. I also use auto pairs and one of the features, called fast wrap or something like that makes use of the <kbd>meta</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> shortcut. However, if I type <kbd>alt</kbd>e inside vim nothing happens except that if I press it three times a Swedish a appears on the screen. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Type `:imap ` ALT+E.   does it type å?  press Enter.  what does it say?

Comment: It does type å after I hit enter

Comment: If I type it several times at some point it also says @<C-R>=AutoPairsFastWrap()<CR>

Comment: alt-mappings are not really portable and depend on the plattform and terminal/gui to work reliably. Therefore, I would suggest, use a different mapping and also create an issue with that specific plugin.

Comment: Unfurtanatly rebind is only solution
e.g.
let g:AutoPairsShortcutFastWrap='<another key>'

Answer (score 1):

I just answered yesterday a question from an AutoPair user about [displaying all meta-key equivalents for regular characters](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13994/display-human-readable-meta-alt-key-mappings). That user was fortunate enough to be on a system where <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *key* consistently emits actual characters. In the course of answering I found that I could also use meta-keys in gVim on Windows but get strange results otherwise from Cygwin terminal Vim and when I use Vim after I SSH into Centos or Ubuntu machines.

So to reiterate what [Christian said in his comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14003/autopairs-shortcut-not-working#comment24025_14003) your best bet if you don't fall into the lucky group is to change the mappings to use key combinations that actually work for you.

**TL;DR** A *portable* solution would require using something other than "Alt" mappings.

Comment: In short, Alt remaps sometimes don't work, and the best solution is to change them

Comment: Well, they work consistently on my Windows systems. I could, for instance, safely use Alt mappings in my .gvimrc if I were so inclined. One short summation I would fully endorse is  "...the _only portable_ solution is to change them." :)